# iai_kinect2 /dev/dri/card0 not authenticated

Tags: ros, iai-kinect2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ROS users, I have a problem with iai_kinect2 package (Indigo). I can successfully use Kinect V2 on my Intel NUC. I am not able to use it when the computer does not have the monitor plugged (through ssh). When I launch `roslaunch kinect2_bridge kinect2_bridge.launch`

I got this error:

> /dev/dri/card0 not authenticated

Is it possible to run kinect2_bridge without a screen monitor?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253722/iai_kinect2-/dev/dri/card0-not-authenticated/) by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 620 on 2017-02-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-03**:
I believe `iai_kinect2` uses OpenGL (perhaps even by default). I can imagine that some of the driver infrastructure needed for that is not active when you don't have your monitor plugged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am posting my workaround in case it helps someone else. I solved adding the user to video group and modifying the /etc/default/grub in this way: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash drm.rnodes=1"`.
After `update grub` it worked.

---

Originally posted by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) with karma: 620 on 2017-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bmastay](https://answers.ros.org/users/36113/bmastay/) on 2018-07-18**:
I also had to add my user to the video group